# Is there a canonical variable for period and group?

Tags: terminology, periodic-trends, notation, periodic-table

For example, "Z" is the standard symbol for atomic number. I'm writing a manuscript that uses the group and period of elements within some equations, and so far I'm just denoting them as $G_{table}$ and $P_{table}$, defining them in the paragraph before the equation is presented. But there are a couple of concerns with that, namely:

1. If there is a canonical symbol that I forgot after undergrad, I'll look rather silly to a reviewer
2. A reader skimming the paper might confuse those symbols for Gibbs free energy or pressure

Is there a standard variable that's commonly used to denote the group or period of an element within an equation?

Comment: Don't worry too much about a reviewer. They are after human beings like us. No there is no symbol for periods or groups.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't totally failing at google!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a standard symbol. However, if you choose these current symbols, please note that "table" should be placed in upright font, not italics:

- correct: `G_{\text{table}}` $G_{\text{table}}$
- wrong: `G_{table}` $G_{table}$

The reason is because "table" is a plain old English word. You can see [Which symbols are written in roman (upright) font and which are italicized?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/16683) for more information; even though that post was written mainly for Chem.SE, the information there is applicable to all of chemistry. The [IUPAC Green Book](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf) writes (Section 1.3.1)

> Subscripts and superscripts that are themselves symbols for physical quantities or for numbers should be printed in italic type; other subscripts and superscripts should be printed in Roman (upright) type.

and other sources such as the ACS Style Guide have similar recommendations.

Personally, if I were you I'd just cut the subscript altogether, unless it's likely to lead to confusion. No need for clunky symbols. For example, [Euler's polyhedron formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) usually just reads

$$V - E + F = 2$$

instead of something like

$$n_\text{vertex} - n_\text{edge} + n_\text{face} = 2.$$